# Given a Date "03/13/2010", using that in a MYSQL Where Clause?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, coldfusion

I would like to pass a MYSQL query via Coldfusion the following date: 03/13/2010
So the query filters against it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE dateAdded before or on 03/13/2010
```

I'd also like to be able to take 2 dates as ranges, from: 01/11/2000, to: 03/13/2010

```
SELECT *
FROMT myTable
WHERE dateAdded is ON or Between 01/11/2000 through 03/13/2010
```

Also, Is there a way to have one query that can handle either BOTH Date_Start and Date_END, or just one of the two?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cfqueryparam with a cfsqltype of CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP.
Given both a "startDate" and "endDate" variable the below code should work. If either startDate or endDate is set to something like false then it won't be included:

```
<cfset startDate = createDate(2010, 01, 19) />
<cfset endDate  = createDate(2010, 01, 26) />

<cfquery name="q" datasource="#request.dsn#">
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE 
    (
        <cfif isDate(startDate)>
            dateAdded >= <cfqueryparam value="#dateFormat(startDate, "YYYY/MM/DD")#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" />
        </cfif>
        <cfif isDate(endDate)>
            <cfif isDate(startDate)>AND</cfif>
            dateAdded <= <cfqueryparam value="#dateFormat(endDate, "YYYY/MM/DD")#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP" />
        </cfif>
    )
</cfquery>
```

Try running the same thing, but with either startDate or endDate set to false such as below to see how it all works in a single query:

```
<cfset startDate = false />
<cfquery name="q" datasource="#request.dsn#">....
```

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot format your date to `YYYY-MM-DD` in Coldfusion, you can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function in MySQL as follows:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    dateAdded <= STR_TO_DATE('03/13/2010','%m/%d/%Y');
```

And...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    dateAdded BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2000','%m/%d/%Y') AND 
                      STR_TO_DATE('03/13/2010','%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: Is there a way to have one query that can handle either BOTH Date_Start and Date_END, or just one of the two?

Comment: @nobosh: Would it be possible to show us your coldfusion code? We may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: @nobosh: Sorry, I just noticed that your date is in MM/DD format not DD/MM. Fixed my answer.

Comment: dateAdded is a timestamp in the DB, so I added a DATE_FORMAT(dateAdded) which seemed to help... The error is now: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('03/01/2010','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('03/24/2010','' at line 22

Comment: Is there a reason why m & d are lowercase but Y is caps?

Comment: Another issue here that I'm seeing is that it says BETWEEN,, if the date_to is 3/13/2010, right now that's not coming back since it's equal to.. Is there a way to update the above to work for equal to?

Comment: Yes `Y` in caps means year in 4 digits. `M` in caps would mean a long month name, such as January, February, etc. Full details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo, thanks I didn't know that... I'm still confused why it's not returning records for TODAY.. Here is the line, note the Date Added is a timestamp, could that be the issue? 
AND (myTable.dateAdded)
   BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('#attributes.datepicker_from#','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('#attributes.datepicker_to#','%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: @nobosh: The `BETWEEN` operator is equivalent to `>= AND <=`, so it should include the start date and the end date. Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: @nobosh: I guess the reason that your query is not returning results for today is because the dateAdded field is a DateTime field, and includes the time (not just the date). Therefore `03/13/2010 11:00:00` would be bigger than `03/13/2010`. To fix that, you can include 23:59:59 to the end date like this: `AND STR_TO_DATE('#attributes.datepicker_to# 23:59:59','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: That makes sense. So I need to convert the dateTime field to a date field?

Comment: Of course you can format the date in ColdFusion: `dateFormat(myDate,"yyyy-mm-dd")`. Shouldn't be strictly necessary, though; if you're using CFQUERYPARAM the format of the date should be adjusted for you based on the database driver being used.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it in Coldfusion would be to use cfqueryparam to manage the translation of the string to a date object as well as providing a level of SQL injection prevention.

```
<cfset myResult = queryNew("id")>
<cfset startDate = "01/11/2000">
<cfset endDate = dateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")>

<cfquery name="myResult" datasource="myDatasource">
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE dateAdded BETWEEN <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#startDate#">
    AND <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#endDate#">
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="myResult">
 ...output code here
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE dateAdded <= YourdateValue
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE dateAdded BETWEEN YourdateValueStart AND YourdateValueEnd
```

Have a look at [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

> This is the inverse of the
>   DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a
>   string str and a format string format.
>   STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value
>   if the format string contains both
>   date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME
>   value if the string contains only date
>   or time parts. If the date, time, or
>   datetime value extracted from str is
>   illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL
>   and produces a warning.  The server
>   scans str attempting to match format
>   to it. The format string can contain
>   literal characters and format
>   specifiers beginning with %. Literal
>   characters in format must match
>   literally in str. Format specifiers in
>   format must match a date or time part
>   in str. For the specifiers that can be
>   used in format, see the DATE_FORMAT()
>   function description.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable  
WHERE (dateAdded <= YourdateValueStart AND YourdateValueEnd  IS NULL)
OR  (dateAdded >= YourdateValueEnd AND YourdateValueStart  IS NULL)
OR (dateAdded BETWEEN YourdateValueStart AND YourdateValueEnd)
```

Comment: How do I format the string "03/12/2010" to be acceptable for  what you have above: YourdateValue

Answer (score -1):

I believe in MySQL you can use comparison operators on dates

so I think you can

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE dateAdded  <= 20100111

and

SELECT *
FROMT myTable
WHERE dateAdded is  BETWEEN 20000111 AND 20100303
```

In general, here's a list of date manipulation functions that mySQL offers:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.htm