# vb.net with mysql how to pick between to dates of different years?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker, custom-formatting

I have a vb.net program that queries a mysql database. i can search and get records between to dates with this code:

```
sqlQRY12 = "SELECT * from mating WHERE date BETWEEN '" & export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.Text & "' AND '" & export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Text & "' AND chkbox = '0' ORDER BY lot_id ASC"
```

my format for my date is:

```
        export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yy"

    export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
```

however if i try to search between two years like 12/20/13 - 02/20/14 I return no records when i know they exist? Any help would be great ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally dates expressed as strings in database queries should be in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

You essentially want your executed query to be this:

```
SELECT * from mating
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-12-20' AND '2014-02-20'
```

So change the format of your dtpickers to be yyyy-mm-dd like this:

```
export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Comment: Alternatively, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440577/given-a-date-03-13-2010-using-that-in-a-mysql-where-clause) that shows how to use STR_TO_DATE() function in MySql. This alternative will be nicer for you if you really like to keep the mm/dd/yy display format in your VB app.

Comment: I have looked at the post and i think the STR_TO_DATE() function will be very useful ty. And yes i do prefer to use that date format being that this program has been in use for a few months. this data is already in this format in the database. It wasn't till the new year hit that we discovered the problem.

Comment: ok i changed my query to:  `sqlQRY12 = "SELECT * from mating WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" & export_daily_date_DateTimePicker1.Text & "','%m/%d/%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" & export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Text & "','%m/%d/%y') AND chkbox = '0' ORDER BY lot_id ASC"`      but i am still not getting any records. no errors either. any help would be great. ty

Comment: At this point you need to troubleshoot in 2 parts:1) Make sure you are building the right query for the DB. Do this by writing the query manually in MySql and ensuring you get the results you want. 2) Make sure your website is generating the same SQL for the query. Do some debug to capture the actual SQL that is being assembled, and make sure it's actually what you were wanting from #1.

Comment: By the way... make sure your 1st Date value has the right year. Looks like you're wanting to retrieve data between m/d/2013 and m/d/2014. But datetimepickers usually default to the current year. So it would be an easy mistake to set the 1st one to Dec.2014 rather than Dec.2013. Also make sure you haven't switched the two dates around. I believe querying for `date BETWEEN date_A AND date_B` expects that date_A is less than date_B (interprets as `X >= date_A AND X <= date_B`). So if you've mixed them up you'd get no results.

Comment: ty for the advise. I have tried a query on the mysql. still no records. i have changed the year in the first datetimepicker. i wonder if it could be caused by the fact that im using a two didgit date as opposed to a 4-digit date?

Comment: If the 2-digit date is the issue i fear i will have to write a mysql script to reformat all the entries with the correct date format. with 80,000+ entries i am not looking forward to that being the possible problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should never concatenate values into your SQL commands.  If at all possible, you should use parameters.  With parameters, you can specify the value as it's actual type (`Date`) rather than as the string representation.  The ADO Provider will handle converting the value correctly for you.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from mating WHERE date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 AND chkbox = '0' ORDER BY lot_id ASC"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", export_daily_date_DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

Comment: ty i will have to see what i can do to improve this problem.

Comment: I agree with this statement in general. For newbs, the reason is that SQL queries built from concatenated inputs are prone to Sql-Injection attacks (attacker sends a specially designed value that causes the query to fetch records plus perform an action as a 2nd statement). The parameter approach is not susceptible to this (the DB will throw exception and not execute if @date1 is anything but a date).
However, in Aaron's specific case it might not be a problem; if using ASP WebForms the dtpicker.Value may be validated before it gets to the point of querying. Still it's a best practice not to.

Comment: The database is only accessed in a LAN environment. Also, its strictly software access. and the ip addresses allowed are set to only the machines allowed to access the database.